How do I transfer data from pandas Dataframe to a Dataframe variable of a different type
So I have a Dataframe of car data which has a price column.

So I want to transfer the data from the price column a variable which is a Dataframe which has the same data as the original column, but I don't want to modify the original Dataframe.
So far I have tried this
# Group columns of the car sales DataFrame by the Make column and find the average
price_list = car_sales["Price"].str.replace("$", "").replace(",", "")
price_data = pd.to_numeric(price_list, errors="coerce")
car_sales.groupby("Make")[price_data].mean()

The issue is that while I am getting the cleaned data contained in price_list is not in the correct format to be passed in as an argument to the to_numeric function. The to_numeric function keeps returning NaN where the price data should be.


I think the problem was probably the fact that I was using the replace function wrong, but anyway I have found another way to do this which is to use the copy function.
car_sales_cp = car_sales.copy()
car_sales_cp["Price"] = car_sales_cp["Price"].str.replace(r"[$,]", "", regex=True)
car_sales_cp["Price"] = pd.to_numeric(car_sales_cp["Price"])
car_sales_cp.groupby("Make")["Price"].mean()


Example Code
The sample should be provided as text or code to be generated, not as an image.
import pandas as pd
data = {
    "Make": ["Toyota", "Honda", "Toyota", "BMW", "Nissan"],
    "Colour": ["White", "Red", "Blue", "Black", "White"],
    "Odometer (KM)": [150043, 87899, 32549, 11179, 213095],
    "Doors": [4, 4, 3, 5, 4],
    "Price": ["$4,000.00", "$5,000.00", "$7,000.00", "$22,000.00", "$3,500.00"]
}

car_sales = pd.DataFrame(data)

car_sales
     Make Colour  Odometer (KM)  Doors       Price
0  Toyota  White         150043      4   $4,000.00
1   Honda    Red          87899      4   $5,000.00
2  Toyota   Blue          32549      3   $7,000.00
3     BMW  Black          11179      5  $22,000.00
4  Nissan  White         213095      4   $3,500.00

Code
Convert the Price column to a numeric series and then perform a groupby using car_sales['Make'] as the grouper.
out = (
    pd.to_numeric(
        car_sales['Price'].str.replace("[$,]", "", regex=True), 
        errors='coerce'
    )  # convert to numeric series
    .groupby(car_sales['Make'])  # grouper
    .mean()
)

out
Make
BMW       22000.0
Honda      5000.0
Nissan     3500.0
Toyota     5500.0
Name: Price, dtype: float64


Another possible solution, whose steps are:

First, it uses the assign method to create a new dataframe with an updated Price column, where the str.replace function removes dollar signs and commas from the Price values, and astype(float) converts the cleaned strings to floats.

Then, the groupby method groups by the Make column, and the mean function calculates the average price for each group.


(car_sales.assign(
    Price = car_sales['Price']
    .str.replace(r'\$|\,', '', regex=True).astype(float))
.groupby('Make')['Price'].mean())

Output
Make
BMW       22000.0
Honda      5000.0
Nissan     3500.0
Toyota     5500.0
Name: Price, dtype: float64

